# How to display company_name instead of company_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a model where I store my `jobdescription`, and a view `Jobdetails` to display the job to the outside world, But I have an issue when I want to display `company_name` from my `Company` model on that view intead of the `company_id`.

I tried different ways and it's still not working.

So, I don't know how to build the query in my controller, if you can tell me where the issue is, that would be very kind of you. Thanks.

**`Schema.rb`**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150212182839) do


  create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "jobdescriptions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "applyjobid"
    t.string   "job_title"
    t.string   "department"
    t.text     "shift"
    t.string   "work_location"
    t.string   "position_supervisor"
    t.string   "supervisor_position_supervisor"
    t.decimal  "rate_pay"
    t.text     "benefits"
    t.text     "other_benefits"
    t.text     "job_summary"
    t.text     "job_duties"
    t.text     "tasks"
    t.text     "results"
    t.text     "responsibilities"
    t.text     "knowledge"
    t.text     "skills"
    t.text     "abilities"
    t.text     "physical_requirement"
    t.text     "work_envir_condition"
    t.text     "protective_clothing_and_devices_required"
    t.text     "tools_or_equipment_required"
    t.text     "qualifications"
    t.text     "education_and_training"
    t.text     "license_certification"
    t.text     "experience"
    t.text     "aptitudes_interests_temperament"
    t.text     "roles_relationships"
    t.text     "supervisory_responsibility"
    t.text     "advancement_promotion_opportunities"
    t.string   "internal_comment"
    t.string   "submited_by"
    t.string   "approved_by"
    t.string   "statut"
    t.date     "from_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "jobdescriptions", ["company_id"], name: "index_jobdescriptions_on_company_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "role_id"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.string   "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count", default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.integer  "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["company_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_id"

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id"

end
```

Here is my **`JobdescriptionsController`**

```
class JobdescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'

  def new
    @jobdescription = Jobdescription.new
  end

  def create
    @jobdescription = current_user.company_id.jobdescriptions.create(jobdescription_params)
    redirect_to new_jobdescription_path
  end

  private

    def jobdescription_params
        params.require(:jobdescription).permit(:applyjobid, :job_title, :work_location, :rate_pay, :shift, )
    end
end
```

**`Jobdetails Controller`**

```
 class JobdetailsController < ApplicationController
   layout 'apply'

       def show
         @jobdetail = Jobdescription.find_by_applyjobid(params[:applyjobid])
         @nm = @jobdetail.company_name
       end

   end
```

Model **`Jobdescription`**

```
  class Jobdescription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
  end
```

Model **`Company`**

```
 class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   has_many :jobdescriptions
 end
```

View **`Jobdetails/show`**

```
 <strong>Company name:</strong>
 <%= @nm %>
```

Comment: What's not working exactly? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I can't get company_name from jobdescription model on my jobdetails view, I switched my computer off now but I think I had no method error.

Comment: OK, I see the issue - I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: please, format the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Jobdetail` model does not have a `company_name` method, but `Company` does.  Just change the `@nm` assignment to grab the company name through the company association:

```
@nm = @jobdetail.company.company_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add company_name as method in your model, as if you are using it multiple times.

```
def company_name
 company.company_name
end
```

then you would be able to use it directly

```
@jobdetail.company_name
```